# Twig - stylesheets can't find my namespaced path

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have added a namespaced path in my app/config.yml for twig:

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/ifm/campaigns-bundle/Resources/views/": sg_cp
```

In a template I have the following twig code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% stylesheets
            '@sg_cp/000000/less/test.css'
            debug=true
            filter='cssrewrite' output='css/compiled/app.css' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi {% include('@sg_cp/000000/include.html.twig') %}
    </body>
</html>
```

The include works, but the stylesheets call fails, it cannot find the namespaced twig path. I have noticed that stylesheets has another format /bundles/mybundle/ but that fails as well. Does stylesheets support namespaced paths?

Comment: Is your bundle named `sg_cpBundle`?

Comment: No, stylesheets do not support namespaced twig paths.  Different concepts.

Comment: @cerad include and stylesheets use different mechanisms for determining filepaths? What I want to accomplish is have a less verbose way of providing paths, one solution is to use a twig function helper that returns the path as a string, but stylesheets tokenizer supports nothing but a literal string, it can't even support a variable being passed in. The only solution i can find is doing '@IfmCampaignsBundle/Resources/views/000000/less/test.css' which becomes painfully repetative and will be very difficult to maintain if anything changes.

Comment: Correct.  Totally different mechanisms and concepts.  More info here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/index.html but keep in mind that while twig templates are included and processed server side, the whole idea behind css to to generate a url pointing to them for loading browser side.  It is perhaps one reason why the assetic bundle is no longer included by default in S3.

Comment: I think part of the problem is you are using assetic here. If you used the symfony `asset` component, you would be able to use your namespaces path (I think).

Comment: asset and assetic serve two different purposes. at first blush assetic appears to be the promised land, where you can combine and compile css/js without spreading the logic throughout controllers.

but if assetic is no longer the way to do this, I may have to find an alternative  approach.